# LARAVEL hasManyThrough still using the ID as foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hi trying to get the rest day of a country. But I am getting error.

Basically here is the structure

Employee
  has SITE,
Site
  has REGION,
Region
  has REST DAY

I have declared this on my Employee Model

```
public function restdays() 
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\ref_restdays', 'App\ref_gacomsit', 'region', 'region');
}
```

But I get this error

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'RUAE' to data type int. (SQL: select [ref_restdays].*, [ref_gacomsit].[region] from [ref_restdays] inner join [ref_gacomsit] on [ref_gacomsit].[id] = [ref_restdays].[region] where [ref_gacomsit].[region] in (855))
```

Apparently it using still the ID of my site masterfile where as I have declared to use the REGION foreign key.

Can anyone explain where is my mistake is? Appreciate for your help.

Comment: Please post the migrations of all the tables involved.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I don't have migration of all the tables since this is a legacy system that I am trying to upgrade to Laravel framework. Only the ref_restdays table is the new table in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I don't need to use hasManyThrough. I've just declared hasMany on my site masterfile like so:

```
public function restdays() 
{
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\ref_restdays', 'region', 'region');
}
```

then I just use the **nested eager loading** on my query using **dot syntax**.

here is my final query, on the last line I just reference site.restdays to get the list of restdays.

```
$employees = hr_employee::select(
    'hr_employee.id',
    'empno',
    'first_name',
    'family_name',
    'empstatus',
    'empstatus_eff_date',
    'contcatg_code',
    'post_title_code',
    'cs',
    'group_initial_joined',
    'returned_date',
    'mcat2',
    'othours1',
    'othours2',
    'othours3'
)
->where([
    ['empno','=',$empno]
])
->with(['catg', 'post', 'site.restdays'])
->get();
```